# R . removing duplicates with conditions

Tags: r, duplicates

I have the following dataset:

```
ID Visite 200 other Variables 
1  1
1  2
1  4
1  4
1  5
1  6
2  1
2  2
2  3
2  4
2  4
2  6
2  7
3  1
3  2
3  2
3  3
3  4
3  5
4  1
4  2
4  3
```

1. I would like to see which IDs contain duplicates in Visite (here: 1: 2x4; 2: 2x4; 3: 2x3)
2. I would like to change the duplicates to the lower Visite if e.g. at ID 1 visite 4 or the lower visit is missing, to the higher visite if e.g. at ID 2 visite 5 or the higher visit is missing, or delete one whole row including all other values of a person if there is a duplicate but no adjacent visit is missing.

Could you please help me? I tried some codes but nothing worked.

Thank you.
Best
Christina

Answer (score 0):

You can try to filter the duplicates with

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(Visite %in% Visite[duplicated(Visite)])
# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID Visite
  <int>  <int>
1     1      4
2     1      4
3     2      4
4     2      4
5     3      2
6     3      2
```

and change one of the duplicates using

```
df %>%
  # add ID =5 with no adjacent visit
  bind_rows(tibble(ID = c(5,5,5), Visite=c(1,2,2))) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  filter(!(duplicated(Visite) & last(duplicated(Visite)))) %>% 
  mutate(Vistite2 = 1:n()) %>% 
  as.data.frame()
   ID Visite
1   1      1
2   1      2
3   1      4
4   1      4
5   1      5
6   1      6
7   2      1
8   2      2
9   2      3
10  2      4
11  2      4
12  2      6
13  2      7
14  3      1
15  3      2
16  3      2
17  3      3
18  3      4
19  3      5
20  4      1
21  4      2
22  4      3
23  5      1
24  5      2
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The first filter works great. Unfortunately I have 350 IDs with duplicates so I can not add or remove the visit with your second code. Do you have any other idea how to change all the duplicates to the lower or higher visite or delete them?